# centos-webpanel not able to convert https to http

Tags: apache, https, server, web-config, centos-web-panel

I am new to server configuration and currently I have been tasked to change http protocol scheme from https to http.

I have used centos webpanel to host my website. This is their official website `https://control-webpanel.com/`.

I have search a lot on google and also checked `control-webpanel.com` documentations but still not able to convert https scheme to http.

I have tried to remove ssl certificate from my domain but this approach not working.

currently I am using apache server which is by default installed.

So guys if anyone have prior experience with this please help me.

I have attached screenshot of how I have removed ssl certificate from webpanel.
[image]
Thanks